# Rails | Use Nested Attribute as Foreign Type For Polymorphic Association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, ruby-on-rails-6, ruby-on-rails-7

In Rails, I would like to structure my models such that the main record (lets call it `Shipment`) has a detail record (base type: `ShipmentDetail`) that is polymorphic such that the structure of the data can change based upon a nested attribute in another association (let's say: `client.name`).

The `ShipmentDetail` class contains a `payload` jsonb type field with client specific information. It can be sub-classed so that we can pull out that client-specific information easily, such as `ClientA::ShipmentDetail`, `ClientB::ShipmentDetail`, etc. In this way, all ShipmentDetail instances are stored in the same `shipment_details` table in the database.

Where I am having trouble is figuring out how to properly configure the association between Shipment and ShipmentDetail.

Here is the base ShipmentDetail class:

```
class ShipmentDetail < ApplicationRecord
  self.abstract_class = true
  self.table_name = "shipment_details"

  has_one :shipment
end
```

And here is how I have currently attempted to model the Shipment class:

```
class Shipment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client, optional: true

  belongs_to :details, class_name: :shipment_details, \
    polymorphic: true, foreign_key: :id, foreign_type: :client_name, optional: true

end
```

Unfortunately, if I attempt to assign something to the `details` association I get an error like:

```
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `client_name`
```

Please advise on how I can properly model this association - is there a trick to configuring the `foreign_type` to use a nested attribute? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your associations don't match with your description.

> the main record (lets call it Shipment) has a detail record (base type: ShipmentDetail) that is polymorphic such that the structure of the data can change based upon a nested attribute in another association (let's say: client.name).

so **Shipment has a ShipmentDetail**, the associations should be:

```
class Shipment < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :shipment_detail
end

class ShipmentDetail < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shipment
  belongs_to :client
end
```

Client-speficic shipment details can be subclass, and client information can be pull-out:

```
class ClientAShipmentDetail < ShipmentDetail
  def client_data
    if payload['client'] == 'clientA'
     # return Client A data
    end
  end
end

class ClientBShipmentDetail < ShipmentDetail
  def client_data
    if payload['client'] == 'clientB'
     # return Client B data
    end
  end
end
```

In this design, you can get a dynamic instance of Shipment Detail specific class by using ([Single Table Inheritance](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html))

Table `shipment_details` just need to add a string column name `type` so that when `shipment_detail` association is loaded, it will return correct object of class `type`.

Example data:

```
shipments table
id|name|
1|shipment1
2|shipment2

shipment_details table
id|shipment_id|type|
1|1|ClientAShipmentDetail
2|2|ClientBShipmentDetail


shipmment1 = Shipment.find(1)
shipment1.shipment_detail # Return instance of ClientAShipmentDetail class

shipmment2 = Shipment.find(2)
shipment2.shipment_detail # Return instance of ClientBShipmentDetail class
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it isn't polymorphic; I want rails to intelligently use the correct class as per the foreign key and type

Comment: @RyanPierceWilliams you can use Single Table Inheritance, you just need to add a `type` column to `shipment_details` table. You can reference here https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html

Comment: Thanks, I got it working using Single Table Inheritance. Would you mind updating your answer with details about it?